# Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS -touch pad scroll for asus-k55v not working

Tags: 12.04, touchpad

Have tried all the commands over terminal but still could not fix it.

For xinput i got

```
Virtual core pointer                            id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse          id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB 2.0 UVC HD Webcam                     id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

None of the post could help to fix it :(

Answer (score 0):

It started working after the following command in my Asus K43S:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled 'true'
```

[Source](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/10/fix-laptops-touchpadtrackpad-not.html)